# OpenVPN How to Create New User

Tags: networking, ubuntu, vpn, openvpn

I installed OpenVPN to my own server via GitHub. It is working but I want to run in my Asus Router but I need username and password. How can I create user for OpenVPN on Ubuntu 16.04 terminal?

https://github.com/Nyr/openvpn-install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this method can help you to do so:

> To add a user for the OpenVPN Access Server to recognize you will need to open up the linux terminal for the server that OpenVPN-AS is running on. In this example we will be using a popular ssh client called putty since we will be adding users remotely from a Windows Machine.

With this method, you need to add a local user to your Ubuntu and then use this account to access the OpenVPN-AS Client UI (https://your-server-ip-address:943) with the newly created credentials

Choose PAM as the authentication method for Access Server to use; click on PAM in the left menu; then choose Use PAM.

If you would like to set OpenVPN-AS Specific User Permissions; for example: Administrator, AutoLogin, VPN IP Address etc you will need to login to the OpenVPN-AS Admin UI (https://x.x.x.x:943/admin) with an Administrator account and navigate over to the User Permissions page.

Source #1: [How To Add Users To Your OpenVPN Access Server Using PAM](https://openvpn.net/vpn-server-resources/how-to-add-users-to-your-openvpn-access-server-using-pam/)

Source #2: [OpenVPN - How To Add Authorized Users To The VPN](https://openvpn.net/faq/how-to-add-authorized-users-to-the-vpn/)

Comment: Thanks but I do not use Access Server.

Comment: How about this one? https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/add-user-grant-root-privileges-ubuntu-18-04/